# How to Customize the time format using logging.config.fileConfig()

Tags: python

I am using python logging module to write to my log files:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(log_conf_file)
```

The formatter section in my log_conf_file "logging.conf" looks like:

```
[formatter_mylog]
format: %(asctime)s %(message)s
```

This makes my log looks like:

```
2013-05-02 13:39:55,325 mesagebody blablablabla
```

How I can customize the asctime format to output something like:

```
May 02 13:39:55 mesage_body blablablabla
```

I know if it's in python code, you can do something like:

```
# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(message)s",
                          "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But how do you do it via the logging configuration file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[formatter_mylog]
format: %(asctime)s %(message)s
datefmt=%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Not sure if this will change the month to the verbal style.

**Update:**

To implement the verbal style of the month try to use `%b` ([source](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/minimal-example.html))

Answer (score 1):

Below should give your expected output

```
[formatter_mylog]
format: %(asctime)s %(message)s
datefmt=%b %d %H:%M:%S
```